# Problem with NVIDIA G86 on Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I got problems some weeks ago with my NVIDIA G86 (8500 GT), supposedly due to the infamous 295.40 version of the driver. I got errror messges like NVRM: RmInitAdpterFailed. Tried varous sugestions about setting kernel acpi and 
 memory options, but no luck.

I pulled in x-swat and got 302.17, if I remember correctly. It did not help.

People recommended xorg-edgers , so I pulled that in and got kernel 3.5.0.12  and nvidia 304.43 but the problem remained.

Getting slightly panicked, I tried to back back to vanilla 12.04, so I purged nvidia* and located and removed anything on the system that smelled nvidia.

I installed nouveau, cause people said it was great, but as it turns out, my card does not seem to be supported.

Sigh...

So now I fear that I have atmessed up system, and graphics is terrible.
Any help would be appreciated.

Xorg.0.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1189616/

kern.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1189634/

Comment: Also tried 173.14.35, Same problem with RmInitAdapter failed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I got things working again.
It seems as if the graphics card was broken.

I booted up a 12.04 ubuntu installation CD and got the same problem as with my updated system. So, I tested the monitor on another computer and it worked fine.

I have now tossed the G86 card and bought a new GeForce GT 520 and everything works fine.